# Squeezebox can't connect to Logitech Media Server running on PC

Tags: firewall, file-server

Debian 11, I have installed Logitech Media Server to use with Squeezebox player. Server is running on local IP Address: 192.168.10.xxx port 9000. I configured that address on my Squeezebox player, but it cann't connect to media server. I'm guessing that it might be caused by an ufw firewall running on Debian.
I checked ufw status:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
23/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
23/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I set rule for ufw firewall, but that not help:

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.10.103 to any port 9000
```

here is Logitech Media Server Log File:

```
[23-07-29 22:07:20.5102] main::init (377) Starting Logitech Media Server (v8.3.1, 1676361197, Fri 17 Feb 2023 06:37:09 AM CET) perl 5.032001 - x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
[23-07-29 22:07:20.5261] Slim::Utils::IPDetect::_init (138) Warning: Couldn't call connect() - falling back to 127.0.0.1
[23-07-29 22:07:25.6148] main::checkDataSource (1107) Warning: Schema updated or no media found in the database, initiating scan.
[23-07-29 22:07:25.6617] Slim::Utils::Misc::msg (1325) Warning: [22:07:25.6613] EV: error in callback (ignoring): pack_sockaddr: invalid host at /usr/share/squeezeboxserver/lib/AnyEvent/DNS.pm line 1114.
[23-07-29 22:07:25.6621] Slim::Utils::Misc::msg (1325) Warning: [22:07:25.6619] EV: error in callback (ignoring): pack_sockaddr: invalid host at /usr/share/squeezeboxserver/lib/AnyEvent/DNS.pm line 1114.
[23-07-29 22:07:27.6621] Slim::Utils::Misc::msg (1325) Warning: [22:07:27.6619] EV: error in callback (ignoring): pack_sockaddr: invalid host at /usr/share/squeezeboxserver/lib/AnyEvent/DNS.pm line 1114.
[23-07-29 22:07:31.0260] Slim::Plugin::FullTextSearch::Plugin::_initPopularTerms (592) Fulltext index missing or outdated - re-building
[23-07-29 22:07:32.6627] Slim::Utils::Misc::msg (1325) Warning: [22:07:32.6624] EV: error in callback (ignoring): pack_sockaddr: invalid host at /usr/share/squeezeboxserver/lib/AnyEvent/DNS.pm line 1114.
[23-07-29 22:07:32.6632] Slim::Utils::Misc::msg (1325) Warning: [22:07:32.6630] EV: error in callback (ignoring): pack_sockaddr: invalid host at /usr/share/squeezeboxserver/lib/AnyEvent/DNS.pm line 1114.
[23-07-29 22:07:34.6632] Slim::Utils::Misc::msg (1325) Warning: [22:07:34.6630] EV: error in callback (ignoring): pack_sockaddr: invalid host at /usr/share/squeezeboxserver/lib/AnyEvent/DNS.pm line 1114.
[23-07-29 22:07:42.6642] Slim::Utils::Misc::msg (1325) Warning: [22:07:42.6637] EV: error in callback (ignoring): pack_sockaddr: invalid host at /usr/share/squeezeboxserver/lib/AnyEvent/DNS.pm line 1114.
[23-07-29 22:07:42.6649] Slim::Utils::Misc::msg (1325) Warning: [22:07:42.6646] EV: error in callback (ignoring): pack_sockaddr: invalid host at /usr/share/squeezeboxserver/lib/AnyEvent/DNS.pm line 1114.
[23-07-29 22:07:44.6649] Slim::Utils::Misc::msg (1325) Warning: [22:07:44.6645] EV: error in callback (ignoring): pack_sockaddr: invalid host at /usr/share/squeezeboxserver/lib/AnyEvent/DNS.pm line 1114.
[23-07-29 22:07:47.6646] Slim::Networking::Repositories::__ANON__ (147) Failed to fetch https://github.com/LMS-Community/lms-plugin-repository/raw/master/extensions.xml: Couldn't resolve IP address for: github.com
[23-07-29 22:07:47.6656] Slim::Formats::XML::gotErrorViaHTTP (343) Error: getting https://www.mysqueezebox.com/api/sounds/v1/opml
Couldn't resolve IP address for: www.mysqueezebox.com
[23-07-29 22:07:47.6659] Slim::Plugin::Sounds::Plugin::_gotSoundsError (82) Error: Unable to cache Sounds & Effects menu from SN: Couldn't resolve IP address for: www.mysqueezebox.com
[23-07-29 22:07:49.6653] Slim::Formats::XML::gotErrorViaHTTP (343) Error: getting http://opml.radiotime.com/Index.aspx?partnerId=16
Couldn't resolve IP address for: opml.radiotime.com
[23-07-29 22:07:49.6656] Slim::Plugin::InternetRadio::Plugin::_gotRadioError (71) Unable to retrieve radio directory from SN: Couldn't resolve IP address for: opml.radiotime.com
[23-07-29 22:11:25.0107] Slim::Plugin::FullTextSearch::Plugin::_initPopularTerms (592) Fulltext index missing or outdated - re-building
[23-07-29 22:22:18.4412] Slim::Plugin::FullTextSearch::Plugin::_initPopularTerms (592) Fulltext index missing or outdated - re-building
[23-07-29 23:11:40.4945] Slim::Networking::SqueezeNetwork::Players::_disconnect_player_error (457) Disconnect SN player error: 403 Forbidden
[23-07-29 23:17:07.9891] Slim::Networking::SqueezeNetwork::Players::_disconnect_player_error (457) Disconnect SN player error: 403 Forbidden
[23-07-29 23:17:48.4542] Slim::Networking::SqueezeNetwork::Players::_disconnect_player_error (457) Disconnect SN player error: 403 Forbidden
[23-07-30 00:51:13.7244] Slim::Networking::SqueezeNetwork::_error (421) Unable to login to SN: Timed out waiting for data
[23-07-30 00:51:13.7247] Slim::Networking::SqueezeNetwork::_init_error (145) Unable to login to mysqueezebox.com, sync is disabled: Timed out waiting for data
[23-07-30 00:51:13.7253] Slim::Networking::SqueezeNetwork::_init_error (161) will retry in 300 (https://www.mysqueezebox.com)
[23-07-30 00:51:44.0230] Slim::Networking::SqueezeNetwork::_error (421) Unable to login to SN: Timed out waiting for data
[23-07-30 00:51:44.0234] Slim::Networking::SqueezeNetwork::_init_error (145) Unable to login to mysqueezebox.com, sync is disabled: Timed out waiting for data
[23-07-30 00:51:44.0239] Slim::Networking::SqueezeNetwork::_init_error (161) will retry in 600 (https://www.mysqueezebox.com)
[23-07-30 00:56:23.0746] Slim::Utils::Timers::__ANON__ (272) Error: Timer Slim::Networking::SqueezeNetwork::__ANON__ failed: 
[23-07-30 01:25:29.7941] Slim::Networking::SqueezeNetwork::Players::_disconnect_player_error (457) Disconnect SN player error: 403 Forbidden
[23-07-30 03:06:00.8745] Slim::Networking::SqueezeNetwork::_error (421) Unable to login to SN: Invalid mysqueezebox.com username or password.
```

So, the answer is: to allow incoming connections to these ports:

```
sudo ufw allow from IP_OF_YOUR_SQUEEZEBOX proto tcp to any port 9000,9090,3483
```

Comment: You first diagnostic step should be to completely disable the firewall and see if it connects successfully. If it does, then you spend more time looking at your firewall configuration. If it *doesn't*, then maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @larsks, you are right: after disabling the ufw firewall, the player successfully connected to the LMS server. So, what I should change in the ufw firewall rules?

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1442386/19645) might help. If not, the next step would be to use `tcpdump` to log the traffic from the squeezebox and open additional ports based on those results.